# Why does my xfdesktop re-arrange folders automatically?

Tags: linux, xfce, desktop-environment

At random times, random folders get re-arranged on my desktop, it's so annoying! What can I do to let my dear OS know that I'd like my folders to stay where they are because that's the reason I arranged them in that way and they shall not be moved ?

**EDIT:**

My desktop environment is XFCE

Comment: Since no information on your desktop environment is given, I can only suggest you to try right clicking and check if things like auto arrange is on.

Comment: I've done that and I haven't found any options like that and that's the reason I'm here desperately trying to get some help.

Comment: Googling 'xfce arrange desktop icons' gives a lot of questions like that. Apparently xfdesktop does have some difficulties in doing that, especially before 4.10.

Comment: [This Xfce forum thread](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=37689) mentioned that the desktop icon mess happens when reboot for older Xfce releases, but seems resolved in Xfce 4.12. And [this thread](https://bbs.linuxdistrocommunity.com/discussion/801/linux-lite-where-is-the-setting-to-not-rearrange-dt-icons-solved) suggested a possible workaround.

Comment: I found [related post](http://askubuntu.com/q/272647/37165) on Ask Ubuntu, in which OP claimed that similar issue was affecting Xfce 4.12 (opposite to my earlier findings); Workaround exists but not persistent.